# Layout of a page in css

Tags: html, css, layout, header

[the layout I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxlfm.png)
So Im trying to achieve a layout of header shown in the picture below using HTML and CSS. I've started with doing the header and put the logo in the centre and the list business but I'm struggling with putting the logo in the centre and the list business in the corner. I've tried using text align but it hasnt worked and im sure its the float but im not sure the code i should use.
Heres my code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: #ffe9e3;
}

header::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.logo {
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding-top: 23px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="logo"><i>LOGO</i></h1>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">List Your Business</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Please include your code to show exactly what you've done so far.

Comment: I've added the code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could make the header a flexbox and use justify and align to center the logo. Then make the nav absolute positioned to put it up in the top right corner.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

header {
  background: #ffe9e3;
  height: 100px;
}

.logo {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="logo"><i>LOGO</i></h1>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">List Your Business</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can move the logo so its one the same line as the list your business

Comment: So that it's aligned to the top? Remove `align-items: center;` from the `container` class

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can achieve this, but without your actual source code it is hard to work with. If you aren't using flex or grid, then I would say to set the parent element (The header container) to position relative, and then set the logo container itself to position absolute. You can then change the positioning as shown.

```css
#hContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: skyblue;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 10px 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="hContainer">
  <div id="logo">Logo</div>
</div>
```